# Raspberry Pi 4 - Raspbian Opencv Python Webcam Problem

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian, webcam

At Rasberry Pi 4, I'll do image processing with a usb webcam. To do this, I added the OpenCv library to Python. I made the simplest video processing with the following code.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Our operations on the frame come here
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

However, after making the process gives an error like this.

```
select timeout

OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (total() == 0 || data != NULL) in Mat, file /build/opencv-L65chJ/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp, line 431
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "untitled.py", line 8, in <module>
    ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.error: /build/opencv-L65chJ/opencv-3.2.0+dfsg/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:431: error: (-215) total() == 0 || data != NULL in function Mat
```

I searched in many places and could not find the answer. What do you think may be the source or source of the problem?

Comment: Make sure you have an excellent power supply on the Raspberry Pi 4.

Comment: did you make sure that 'camera' is enabled in the raspberry pi configuration?
also, could it be that you have another program using the camera?

Comment: if you have weak power supply then it can even reset system.

Comment: @MarkSetchell yes I am using perfect power supply. I am usşng 5v5a power supply for my project. In fact, there was no problem before. I wanted to start the system with my own splash screen and the system did not respond. So I reinstalled the raspbian system. And I came across a problem like that.

Comment: @FrankMusteman yes I am sure enabled 'camera'. Even I am taking photo with webcam tahnks to 'fswebcam' tool. There was no problem before. I wanted to start the system with my own splash screen and the system did not respond. So I formated and reinstalled the raspbian system. And I came across a problem like that.

Comment: @furas No, I am not using weak power system. I am using 5V5A power supply.

Comment: i had some issues with the raspberry pi4 and the newest opencv dist, while its not a proper solution - it might be worth trying an older version of opencv

Comment: @FrankMusteman I've already used Opencv older version(version = 3.2). I think the problem was with rasberry and driver. For example, I have Rasberry3, it works fine with the same camera and opencv version.

Answer (score 0):

Although I could not find a solution on the subject I mentioned, I felt the need to make some explanations.
Firstly, there are already problems with the Raspberry pi 4 4GB version. These problems are caused by a kernel error, as well as the link below.

Link : https://www.cnx-software.com/2019/11/04/raspberry-pi-4-4gb-models-usb-ports-dont-work-on-ubuntu-19-10/

It is recommended to install ubuntu system on raspberry for this process. The issue here is overcome by limiting RAM to 3072. However, when I tried again, he made the same mistake.

Secondly, I tried the 2 GB version of Raspberry Pi 4. There was no problem with the camera and the problem was solved.

My theory is that the 4GB version of the Raspberry Pi 4 has a problem with the USB ports in general, and I recommend the 1GB or 2GB version to the users.

I hope they fix this problem as soon as possible.
I wish everyone good work.